# Python - Extracting content with tags inside XLM file with lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to extract data from xml files with lxml.
By example : test.xml

```
<document>
    <body>
        <title>test title</title>
        <subtitle>test subtitle</subtitle>
        <content>
            <p>blabla bla bla <em>bla bla</em> blabla bla bla <strong>blabla</strong> blabla</p>
            <p>blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla</p> 
            <p>blabla bla bla <em>bla bla</em> blabla</p>
        </content>
    </body>
</document>
```

To extract title or subtitle, it's ok :

```
from lxml import etree

xmlData = []
tree = '/folder/test/xml'
for title in tree.xpath("/document/body/title"):
    xmlData['title'] = title.text
for subtitle in tree.xpath("/document/body/subtitle"):
    xmlData['subtitle'] = subtitle.text
```

But for content, it's not the same... `for content in tree.xpath("/document/body/content")` doesn't work, I have to try with `for content in tree.xpath("/document/body/content/p")`
However, with that I won't extract em content and strong content.

I need to call tree.xpath("/document/body/content/p/em") and tree.xpath("/document/body/content/strong"). But, in this case, content is separated in three parts and I can't put them together in the right order.
By example, if I try something like :

```
for content in tree.xpath("/document/body/content/p"):
    for em in tree.xpath("/document/body/content/p/em"):
        for strong in tree.xpath("/document/body/content/p/strong"):
            xmlData['content'] = content.text + em.text + strong.text
```

For each paragraph, I will have the same em and strong contents, even for paragraphs which didn't have these tags.

Besides, if I want to keep html tags, I have to add them myself...

```
for content in tree.xpath("/document/body/content/p"):
    xmlData['content'] = '<p>' + content.text + '</p>'
```

Could I just code in order to extract all the content between < content > and < /content > and keep all tags inside ?

Comment: What is the expected output based on the xml you have posted.

Comment: xmlData = ['title': "test title", 'subtitle': "test subtitle", 'content': "<p>blabla bla bla <em>bla bla</em> blabla bla bla <strong>blabla</strong> blabla</p><p>blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla</p><p>blabla bla bla <em>bla bla</em> blabla</p>"]

Comment: have you looked at my answer? do you think you can take it from there?

Answer (score 2):

Using python core XML library ElementTree. No external lib is required.
The idea is to scan the `p` element using a recursive function and collect the text.
The code collects the required info into a dict.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<document>
    <body>
        <title>test title</title>
        <subtitle>test subtitle</subtitle>
        <content>
            <p>jack<em>dan</em>ben<strong>jim</strong>steve</p>
            <p>blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla</p>
            <p>A<em>B</em>C</p>
        </content>
    </body>
</document>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
title = root.find('.//title').text
subtitle = root.find('.//subtitle').text
data = dict(title=title, subtitle=subtitle)
p_list = []
for idx, p in enumerate(root.findall('.//p')):
    p_list.append(ET.tostring(p).strip().decode())
data['content'] = ' '.join(p_list)
print(data)
```

output

```
{'title': 'test title', 'subtitle': 'test subtitle', 'content': '<p>jack<em>dan</em>ben<strong>jim</strong>steve</p> <p>blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla</p> <p>A<em>B</em>C</p>'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could get the same result with lxml with `xmlData = tree.xpath ('// content / * / text ()'
However the output isn't what I neeed because with this method and your method, I lose html tags <p>, <em> and <strong> and I have only their contents.
I would like an output like this:
{'title': 'test title', 'subtitle': 'test subtitle'; 'content': '<p> jack <em> dan </em> ben <strong> jim </strong> steve </p> <p> blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p> <p> A < em> B </em> C </p> '}

Comment: I adapted your code to mine to avoid having to replace lxml.etree with xml.etree everywhere. it gives that :
```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

bodyContent = ''
for body in tree.xpath ("/ document / body / content / p"):
    bodyContent + = ET.tostring (body) .strip (). decode ()
data ['content'] = bodyContent
```

There is probably something cleaner to do without mixing lxml and xml but it works. Thank you

Comment: Consider list comprehension or even generator: `p_list = (ET.tostring(p).strip().decode() for idx, p in enumerate(root.findall('.//p')))`!